# How to read text file in Python using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scatter-plot

I'm new to Pandas and I've been trying to do a scatter plot in Python 2.7, I've the dataset in .txt file something like this (comma separated)

```
6.1101,17.592
5.5277,9.1302
8.5186,13.662
7.0032,11.854
5.8598,6.8233
8.3829,11.886
7.4764,4.3483



import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as mplt

# Taking Dataset using Pandas

input_data = pd.read_csv('data.txt');
#input_data.head(5)
```

How to plot the above data in scatter plot without any headers on the dataset ?

I've seen in tutorials and examples that if the data set has column headings then it's possible to plot the scatter plot. I tried putting x and y as the headers for the two columns of the data set in .txt file and tried the below code.

```
input_data = pd.read_csv('data.txt');
#input_data.head(5)
x_value = input_data[['x']]
y_value = input_data[['y']]

mplt.scatter(x_value, y_value)
```

But still I'm getting error as shown below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\IIT Madras\Research\Experiments\Machine Learning\Linear Regression\Linear_Regression.py", line 16, in <module>
    y_value = input_data[['y']]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1791, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_array(key)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1835, in _getitem_array
    indexer = self.ix._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1112, in _convert_to_indexer
    raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
KeyError: "['y'] not in index"
```

Is there a better way to deal with this (with and without header names) ?

EDIT:

The following worked for me after going through Ishan reply

```
input_data = pd.read_csv('data.txt', header =None);
x_value = input_data[[0]]
y_value = input_data[[1]]
mplt.scatter(x_value, y_value)
mplt.show()
```

Comment: You can either add the headers or names or refer to the columns by their numeric indices. The parameter for `read_csv` is `names`, see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try importing the data without column headers and then naming columns by your own :

```
df=pd.read_csv(r'/home/ishan/Desktop/file',header=None)
df.columns=['x','y']
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(df['x'],df['y'])
plt.show()
```